# Install a .pkg file on Mac in background?

Tags: macos, command, applescript, pkg-file

I have just a simple question.
Is it possible to install .pkg files in background?
I would like to install python but in the background.

Is it possible to do this with applescript or schell commands?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

There's a command line installer at `/usr/sbin/installer`

Typing `man installer` at the shell prompt (in Terminal) will display the documentation.